# WPF - can bind a command to a "SelectedItem" in a DataGrid but cannot call it

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

I have two `DataGrid`s in my View. The first is populated when the ViewModel constructor is called. The second is populated when the user clicks on a row in the first DataGrid.
I think the problem is that I set the action for the second DataGrid (`RowBClickCommand`) when I *run* the action bound to the first DataGrid (`RowAClickCommand`).

Then again, I can't see any reason why it doesn't get called when I click on an item in the second DataGrid.

What is wrong in my approach?

Here's the .xaml file:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
    <DataGrid
    x:Name="ADataGrid"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrSelectedA, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding AData}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp" >
                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                Command="{Binding RowAClickCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>

<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <DataGrid
    x:Name="BDataGrid"
    SelectedItem="{Binding CurrSelectedB, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding BData}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp" >
                <i:InvokeCommandAction
                Command="{Binding RowBClickCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The ViewModel is defined as follows:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ICommand RowAClickCommand { get { return _rowAClickCommand; } }
    public ICommand RowBClickCommand { get { return _rowBClickCommand; } }
    // ...

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        _rowAClickCommand = new MainWindow.DelegateCommand(() =>
        {
            _rowBClickCommand = new MainWindow.DelegateCommand(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("x");
            });

            var complexTypeB = new ComplexTypeB();
            _Bdata = new ObservableCollection<B>(complexTypeB.l);
            OnPropertyChanged("BData");

            BView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_Bdata);

            BView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_Bdata);
            BView.CurrentChanged += delegate
            {
                _currSelectedB = (B)BView.CurrentItem;
            };
        });

        var someComplexTypeInstance = new ComplexTypeA();
        _Adata = new ObservableCollection<A>(someComplexTypeInstance.l);

        AView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(_Adata);
        AView.CurrentChanged += delegate
        {
            _currSelectedA = (A)AView.CurrentItem;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `OnPropertyChanged("RowBClickCommand")` after `_rowBClickCommand` is set to something else.  Something like this:

```
_rowAClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
{
    MessageBox.Show("ACalled");
    _rowBClickCommand = new DelegateCommand(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("BCalled");
    });

    OnPropertyChanged("RowBClickCommand");   
});
```

Comment: Precisely. It's the second time that `OnPropertyChanged` bites me.

Comment: One thing that helps me at least is to call `OnPropertyChanged` in the property setter.  That should help cut down on little mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change binding of your commands as follows:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction
    Command="{Binding RowAClickCommand, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor
                                                     AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

Similarly:

```
<i:InvokeCommandAction
    Command="{Binding RowBClickCommand, 
                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor
                                                     AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
```

Comment: Tried but it didn't fix the issue unfortunately. The thing is, according to Resharper, both `RowAClickCommand` and `RowBClickCommand` seem to be correctly bound.

Comment: @Jir can you post a sample project?